# Change user in testing time

Tags: asp.net

I want to change or switch user in asp.net web application at time of automation testing. As there is no login page. The web application directly take user id from OS using (user.identification) and send to third party application and that send all the details of user like that user get login into web app. 
Any one can tell me how change or switch user when do testing using protractor?